# How a can changes in the UI alter a ListView of Objects SelecteItem properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a List of Cube objects, my ListView shows the names of those cubes, once a cube is selected, it's properties are displayed in different TextBoxes, Those are already bound to the SelectedItem. However, I haven't figured out a way using Xaml to bind the SelectedItem's properties to those TextBoxes so that the changes are to be applied immediately.

I have already tried achieving that using TextChanged event, but I thought maybe there is a way of achieving that in a better way.

Edit: here's how it basically works.

```
listOfCubes.ItemsSource = cubes; //setting the source of type Cube
```

binding the view

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

One example of a textBox

```
 <TextBox TextChanged="Cube_TextChanged"
          Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.RotateTransform.Rotation.Axis.X,
                         ElementName=listOfCubes}">
```

what I'm trying to replace

```
private void Cube_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //apply changes in Properties to the selected cube
}
```

Comment: could you please show your code :)

Comment: Do you already have a view model with properties for the collection of Cubes and the selected Cube?

Comment: You don't bind the selecteditem itself, you bind what the selecteditem is bound to.

Comment: I'm not literally asking to bind the SelectedItem, I'm asking how to change cubes's properties based on selection.

Comment: You path is pointing to selecteditem, since you've shown no other properties in the class, just what IS it supposed to be pointing to?  Normally, on your listview you would have SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedCube}" or something like that, and then your textbox would bind to Text="{Binding MySelectedCube.x}".  MySelectedCube being a property of Cube that is in your class somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using the TwoWay binding mode.

```
<TextBox TextChanged="Cube_TextChanged"
      Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.RotateTransform.Rotation.Axis.X,
                     ElementName=listOfCubes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it correctly: you need only to update your staff when its value is changed

so basically add this to your ViewModel

```
 public double X 
 {
   get => mX;
   set 
   {
       mX = value;
       OnXChanged();
       //notify
   }
 }
 private double mX;


 private void OnXChanged()
 {
    //your code
 }
```

then bind it like this, **DONT FORGET ->** `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.RotateTransform.Rotation.Axis.X,
                         ElementName=listOfCubes,
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

**or** if you need to change the textbox text

add this to your viewmodel

```
 public double Text 
 {
   get => mText;
   set 
   {
       mText = value;
       OnTextChanged();
       //notify
   }
 }
 private double mText;


 private void OnTextChanged()
 {
    //your code
 }
```

XAML

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

**or** if you want to have both values (x and textbox text) in one place

```
 <TextBlox>
    <TextBlox.Text>    
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YOUR_MULTI_CONVERTER}"
                      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="Text" />
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.RotateTransform.Rotation.Axis.X"
                     ElementName="listOfCubes" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlox.Text>
</TextBlox>
```